# Browser to browser calls with free account press any key to continue?

Tags: twilio

I am trying out twilio using the [quick start tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/ruby/client/browser-to-browser-calls). I am doing browser to browser calls. I have followed the tutorial. When I try to make a call it rings and connects. It then plays the "free account" message and asks me to press any key to continue. When I press a key it does nothing for a few seconds and then hangs up without going through to the other browser.

Is this happening because I am on a free account or is there something else I need to do in order for it to register the key press from the browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

I can see where this might be confusing and its good feedback.  The prompt to *press any key* is apparently making the assumption that you are calling from an actual phone, which would include a keypad that lets you press any key.  Obviously with a simple Twilio Client app there isn't by default a number pad to press, but the JavaScript SDK does include the [sendDigits](https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/connection#sendDigits) function, which makes it pretty trivial to wire up a button (or some other UI) in your app to send the equivalent of a key press (aka a DTMF tone) to Twilio.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. I was stuck in the same scenario in Android. There is a sendDigits() function in android too. That did the trick. Thanks Devin.

Comment: @Devin I ran into the same issue that the OP ran into. But after reading your answer, I added a button that does "Twilio.Connection.sendDigits('0')". However, the chrome console is saying that the function is undefined. Any idea why?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to call sendDigits directly on the connection class, not an instance of the connection object.  When you make or receive a call in the Cliekt SDK you will get an instance of the Connection object that you can save as a global variable and then call sendDigits.  Hope that helps.