# Physical phone calls to browser phone using Twilio not working

Tags: javascript, webrtc, twilio

I have followed the [Twilio Client Javascript Quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/client/javascript) guide successfully configured the Node.js app on Heroku with my **demo** Twilio account.

I can use this app to make browser to browser calls (with Twilio IDs), browser to phone (my personal registered number), but **not** phone to browser.

When I do that, I get the typical *free account* message followed by "Press any key to execute your call". I press "any key" on the phone, it does nothing for a while and then the call is disconnected.

I have found this related question:

[Browser to browser calls with free account press any key to continue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274923/browser-to-browser-calls-with-free-account-press-any-key-to-continue)

But it doesn't help me...

I mean, the `sendDigits()` should be invoked on an active `connection` object, but I don't have one. The call from my phone to the browser is never established. However, this doesn't make sense because I'm making a call **from** a phone **to** a browser, the "any key" should be pressed on the phone. At least that's how I interpret it.

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a call from your mobile phone to a Twilio Client instance.

When you make a call from your mobile phone to your Twilio number, Twilio will execute the script located ion your voice URL and retrieve TwiML instructions for handling the call.

Your script should return [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Client>[clientName]</Client>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

Of course you need to make sure that Client instance named [clientName] is online and able to receive incoming connections.